# Embedding python package in C++

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program, which calls a python function. It works fine when the python scripts are in simple directories, but when I create a zip package from them, the PyImport_Import can't find the module.
I have the following file structure:

```
A <dir>
|
| -- pack.zip
     | -- __init__.py
     | -- __main__.py
     | -- asdf.py
     | -- subdir <dir>
          | -- __init__.py
          | -- qwer.py
| -- prog.cpp
```

The running the prog.cpp (prog.exe) should call a function from asdf.py:

```
void func()
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", "../A/pack.zip", 1);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* moduleName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("asdf");
    PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(moduleName);
    if(module != nullptr) {
        PyObject* pyFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "f");
        if(pyFunc != nullptr && PyCallable_Check(pyFunc)) {
            PyObject* result = PyObject_CallObject(pyFunc, nullptr);
        }
    }
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

I tried different paths in the setenv (only the directory A, the zip file without the "zip" extension), and also different module names (the pack.zip package, `__main__`, which I guess problematic, because of the `__main__` module created by the Py_Initialize), but nothing worked, it couldn't find the module.
When I run the zip package (python pack) it works fine. As I mentioned if I use a 'pack' directory instead of the zip, it works.
How should I embed a python package in C++?